# Regex Replace pattern extract buf from char buf[10];

Tags: c#, regex

Need a regex pattern for the following:

```
input = "char buf[10];"

To be replaced to input = "String buf = null;"
```

Currently using this, but i'm not too experienced with Regex and am stuck

```
 input = Regex.Replace(input, @"char\s\(.+\)\s*\[\d\]", @"String = $1");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
char\s\(.+\)\s*\[\d\]
      ^^  ^^
```

In the highlighted part of your regular expression, you are matching `(` and `)` characters, which don’t appear in your input text. You will have to remove the escape characters to make it an actual capture group, so you can use its content in the replacement text.

The next problem is that you only match a single digit within the square brackets. You want to accept more than a single digit too, so use `\d+` instead of just `\d`.

And finally, I think your replacement string should be `String $1` as the matched group is the variable name and not the content.

```
Regex.Replace(input, @"char\s(.+)\s*\[\d+\]", @"String $1"); // String buf;
```

Comment: A few other points: do you really need to match \s after "char"? It's probably going to always just be a space, right?  Will there ever be whitespace characters between the char name and the brackets?  If the char name never contains anything other than normal word characters, it would be better to use "\w" instead of ".".  Lastly, you don't need to escape the ] because it's not a special character unless it's following an unclosed [.  That said, the regex could be reduced to: `char (\w+)\[\d+]`